# In magnetic disk, 1 page belong to only 1 block?

Tags: sql-server, disk

this is a part of my teacher's slide about magnetic disk:

> Data files are decomposed into pages
> • Fixed size piece of contiguous information in the file
> • Unit of exchange between disk and main memory
> The disk is divided into blocks which have same size as pages
> • So that a page can be stored in any block

I confused the quote "Data files are decomposed into pages": Does 1 file is decomposed into many pages or 1 page can contains some data combination of (may be) more than 1 file!?

The same confusion for "...So that a page can be stored in any block": in the above statement, as I understand a block have same size as a page, so a page is just stored only in a block that has same size but what does 'any' mean in there?

Comment: I don't believe this is accurate.  My understanding is that disks have blocks, which are addressable and pages are more of a construct within the database.  A "page" can be one or more blocks.  Or block can contain multiple "pages".

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit of a simplification

- A table is stored on 8KB Pages
- Each 8 Pages for the table are grouped into a 64KB Extent
- An Extent is stored at some offset in a File*
- A File is stored on a Volume, which is formatted with a File System and an Allocation Unit Size
- A Volume is stored on a Disk
- A Disk is striped and/or replicated across 1 or more Physical Disks*

In SQL Server Pages are always 8KB, but in Windows a Volume can use any block size.  4KB and 64KB are the most common.  The File System manages the File metadata and stores each File as a number of blocks on the Volume.

*A File is a logical OS construct that has a name and a logically contiguous range of bytes from position 0 to N.

*A "Physical Disk" is managed either by a RAID array, a SAN device, or a Windows Storage Space

On that slide the first two bullets are correct: A Table is stored as 8KB Pages which are fetched as needed into the Page Cache for use by queries.

The rest of the Storage details are not often relevant for SQL Server, and the last two bullets:

> The disk is divided into blocks which have same size as pages
>
> • So that a page can be stored in any block

are not really correct or meaningful.